# javax.swing.Timer equivalent in SWT?

Tags: java, timer, swt

I need some means to run code on user-interface thread with delay and with ability to abort waiting. This can be done by `javax.swing.Timer` in `Swing`. Is there similar functionality in `SWT`? `Display#timerExec` has no apparent ability to cancel future running.

Comment: Given the entanglement between SWT and Eclipse, I bet they assume `UIJob` covers that.

Comment: Use the java.util.Timer and TimerTask

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194201/creating-a-java-timer-and-a-timertask`

Comment: I do. But wonder if more suitable class exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using `Display#timerExec(int, Runnable)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    final Button runButton = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);
    runButton.setText("Stop");

    final Runnable run = new Runnable()
    {
        private int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(runButton.getSelection())
                return;

            text.setText(Integer.toString(counter++));

            display.timerExec(1000, this);
        }
    };

    display.timerExec(1000, run);

    runButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            if(!runButton.getSelection())
                display.timerExec(1000, run);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(200, shell.getSize().y);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Don't see where are you cancelling action after timer has  started?

Comment: @Dims Just press the button ;) Hint: the logic that stops the `Runnable` is in the `Runnable` itself. It doesn't restart itself if the `Button` has been selected.

Comment: Button just put the chain on pause.

Comment: I see but this is not cancelling, this is pausing.

Comment: @Dims Well, then just remove the `Listener` for `SWT.Selection` from the `Button` and it is cancelling ;)

Comment: No, it is not, it has time to update text. I need to cancel waiting at all, so that operation never performed.

Comment: @Dims The check in the `Runnable` is executed first, so it doesn't update the text, if the `Button` was pressed first...

Comment: @Dims Let me make this crystal clear: Set the initial delay to 10 seconds (`10000`), run the application and directly press the `Button`. Then wait as long as you want, the `Text` isn't updated (unless you press the `Button` again. If that's not cancelling, then I don't know what is.

Comment: Ok. My goal is to free UI thread. I do some update (regular expression) and then program starts searching in one second. If I update regular expression within 800 milliseconds, the scheduled search is not performed and waiting restarts for 1000 new milliseconds. You suggest to split waiting interval into smaller parts, but it will touch UI thread each portion, which is not good.

Comment: I need not just Timer equivalent, but it's cancelation capability

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49100/discussion-between-baz-and-dims)

Answer (score 1):

My goal was to make idle detector to smooth user interface. When user makes changes in one part of UI, then the system waits for 1000 ms and updates other parts of UI. If during the waiting, say in 800 ms, user makes changes again, then system cancels waiting for that period and start to wait for 1000 ms again.

In `Swing` this was solved with one-time delayed timer. Swing's Timer made good for this. And I was wondering, if the same is made in SWT?

Probably there is no direct equivalent, so I made a class with util's Timer:

```
public abstract class DelayedInfrequentAction implements Runnable {

    private int delay;
    private Display display;

    private Timer timer = null;

    public DelayedInfrequentAction(Display display, int delay) {
        this.display = display;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public synchronized void kick() {

        if( timer != null ) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer = null;
        }

        timer = new Timer(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), true);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display.syncExec(DelayedInfrequentAction.this);
                synchronized (DelayedInfrequentAction.this) {
                    timer = null;
                }

            }}, delay);

    }

    @Override
    abstract public void run();

}
```

this is not Swing's Timer equivalent, but utilizes cancelation ability of utils Timer.