# Java timer 100 times per second

Tags: java, time, timer

I'd like to run some method 100 times per second.
What I got is this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            time+= 0.001;
            System.out.println(time);
            repaint();
        }
    });
```

From the output it is clear that timer is faster than it should be. Also it is taking toll on cpu, so i doubt this is right way to do this. If i set  `new Timer(1, new ActionListener()` and `time+= 0.01;` then it is slower than it should be.

Can anyone help me out with this? How do i perform task 100 times per second?

EDIT:
change to:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        time += 0.01;
        System.out.println(time);
        repaint();
    }

}, 1, 1);
```

Not sure if its netbeans but output time is waaay of. Its either to slow or to fast. for example output:

```
57.07999999999721
57.08999999999721
57.09999999999721
57.10999999999721
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 24 seconds)

5.699999999999923
5.709999999999923
5.7199999999999225
5.729999999999922
5.739999999999922
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

EDIT2:
Changed to `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` and it works fine now. THnx @GeorgeG

Comment: Why not set the delay to 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` and run it every 0.01 seconds.

Comment: I have stumbled upon new Timer().schedule , but im having dificulties setting it. Can you give me example pls?

Comment: Take a look at this. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_scheduleatfixedrate.htm Basically you have to define a TimerTask and this method will make it  execute every certain period of time that you will define.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. new Timer(); requires int and ActionListener .jdk1.8

Comment: Take a look at this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html. You will have to use the `Timer()` constructor like this : `Timer timer = new Timer();`. Then, you call the `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method as shown in the example above with the Timertask and the interval.

Comment: constructor Timer in class javax.swing.Timer cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,java.awt.event.ActionListener
  found: no arguments

Comment: You are using the `javax.swing.Timer`, I was talking about the `java.util.Timer`. I should have noticed that. These are two different Timer classes. You can try writing `java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();` and then use the TimerTask for the `repaint()` task. Alternatively, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13198256/3510585

Comment: Beware that `java.util.Timer` does not execute within the context of the EDT, which could cause issues when used with Swing

Answer (score 2):

You can use Thread.sleep(10L). This will sleep thread for 10ms. so it'll execute 100 times per second

Comment: repaint() takes a moment. therefore it will take more than a second to execute it 100 times..

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Thread.sleep()` to the slow the rate of execution.

Comment: repaint() takes a some time. therefore it will take more than a second to execute it 100 times..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i = 100;

while (i-- > 0) {
    myMethod();
    try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: repaint() takes a some time. therefore it will take more than a second to execute it 100 times..