# Waiting for thread while updating Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, real-time

I have problem with handling threads in my application. It creates JFrame and starts a new Thread. Last one will execute external application and update GUI. Then

I have problem to make Main class to wait for second thread to finish, but also to update GUI simultaneously.

Here's my example (shortened):

```
class Main {

    public int status;

    public Main() {

        // Creating GUI etc.

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JDialog id = new JDialog();
                id.button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()); // Calls generate() method
            }

        });

    }

    public void generate() {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // Make changes to GUI
            }

        });

        GeneratorThread genTest = new GeneratorThread(this, 1, 1, 1);
        genTest.start();

        //while (status == 0);

        System.out.println("Next step.");

    }

}
```

And Thread class:

```
public class GeneratorThread extends Thread {

protected Main main;
protected int setSize, minValue, maxValue;

public GeneratorThread(Main main, int setSize, int minValue, int maxValue) {
    this.main = main;
    this.setSize = setSize;
    this.minValue = minValue;
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
}

public void run() {

    // Execute program etc.
    // Change GUI from main in the same time
            // About 3 seconds

    main.status = 1;

}

}
```

I'm in progress and I wanted to check how it works so far. While worked nice, but it locks Swing somehow and any changes are visible only when `GeneratorThread` finishes. I would like to update GUI in the real time.

I've tried `join()`, effects are the same. I also tried `wait()` (on `Main`), but then I got IllegalStateMonitorException.

Any hints?

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE. It's not really clear what you're doing and what you want to do.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you wanted to achieve with the code provided. Though if you wanted to update the GUI, in the sense that updates are done synchronously with the task being performed. You can have a look at [SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)). Here is a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13004927/1057230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded environment.  That is, there is a single thread responsible for managing all the interactions and updates to the Swing UI - the Event Dispatching Thread.

Among the golden rules of Swing are...

- DON'T block the EDT (`Thread.sleep`, `Thread#join`, `Object#wait`, block IO and/or time consuming tasks (among others) should never be called from within the EDT), doing so will stop the EDT from dispatching events and paint updates (amongst other things)
- ONLY create/update Swing UI elements from within the EDT.

This raises a question...how do you "wait" for a thread?

The best way is use an Observer pattern.  Basically, you provide the `Thread` with some kind of reference that it will call to provide notification of events, such as errors and completion...

This will require you to think very carefully about the design of your applications, as you can not rely on a simple A to B execution of your code.

For example...

```
public class TestThreadCallBack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestThreadCallBack();
    }

    public TestThreadCallBack() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface ThreadCallBack {

        public void threadCompleted(Runnable source);

        public void threadFailed(Runnable source);
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ThreadCallBack {

        private JLabel message;
        private JLabel dots;
        private int count;

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            message = new JLabel("Running background task, please wait");
            dots = new JLabel("   ");
            add(message);
            add(dots);

            timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count++;
                    if (count > 3) {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(3);
                    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                        sb.append(".");
                    }
                    for (int index = count; index < 3; index++) {
                        sb.append(" ");
                    }
                    dots.setText(sb.toString());
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();

            Thread thread = new Thread(new BackgroundTask(this));
            thread.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void threadCompleted(Runnable source) {
            timer.stop();
            message.setText("Task completed successfully");
        }

        @Override
        public void threadFailed(Runnable source) {
            timer.stop();
            message.setText("Task failed");
        }
    }

    public class BackgroundTask implements Runnable {

        private ThreadCallBack callBack;

        public BackgroundTask(ThreadCallBack callBack) {
            this.callBack = callBack;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Background task underway...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            }
            int result = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 1));
            if (result == 0) {
                callBack.threadCompleted(this);
            } else {
                callBack.threadFailed(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updating the UI from within a `Thread` other then the EDT is, well, messy.  An easier solution would actually be to use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).  This has publish/process methods that make easy to update the UI and progress methods that can be used to provide feedback about the progress of the current task.

You can use it's `done` method to notify interested parties when the worker has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Update your GUI from within the thread using SwingUtilitied.invokeLater or, alternatively, synchronise the main variable!

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#concurrencyjava

Maybe it already suffices to make "status" volatile?

Comment: What do you mean by synchronising main variable?

Comment: You need to synchronize shared data to ensure its visibility on other threads. Added a link (look at the concurrency chapter).